# Background transparency getting ripped cause of box shadow in IE with CSS3 PIE ?

Tags: css, css3pie

I ve searched and found many things in web for a box shadow in IE most of the people showed me that they are using [CSS3 PIE](http://css3pie.com/documentation/supported-css3-features/) but it has a problem with transparent background. i dont wanna put another picture over my buttons i wanna make them transparent and with some shadow at the edges but as usual while chrome - safari - mozilla can do that IE cant do a ...thing.

I ve been wondering what would be the fastest and easiest way to put some shadow to the edges of my button without getting my background fullfilled with shadow effect.

Meanwhile in somewhere there is a guy who screams cause of a world wide known web killer :

"**I hate you IE!**"

Comment: Do you have a link to what you've tried so far?

Comment: i didnt publish my website yet! im using mvc3 trying out before publishing. My problem is when u set the background of an element as transparent, u see the boxshadow istead of background of the parent element. Its cause of css3 pie putting a filtered picture under ur element and when u make its background transparent u will see that picture instead of parent elements background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pie's opaque box-shadow is an understandable limitation for pre-IE9 browsers, but I'm afraid it is the best option you have.  So either design your UI without transparent backgrounds (for the areas that use box-shadows) or create button graphics complete with shadow using PNG format.

Perhaps take a look at [switchitoff.net](http://switchitoff.net) (in IE8) and see how I did my buttons and popup dialogs. These all have subtle shadows, round corners and lots of lovely chopped up graphics behind the scenes. But there really was no other way for pre-IE9.  It switches to CSS3 for all the good browsers.

Comment: i was afraid of this answer but its true and i liked ur interactive help there nice thought.